# PC Health Check won't open

Tags: windows-10

[image for the app in the start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zdF3.png)

I can't open PC Health Check app

I tried:

1. Uninstall
2. Reinstall from [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11?ocid=wu_windows_app_omc_win#pchealthcheck) then restarted
3. The app did an update, then nothing
4. Another restart and still nothing
5. Repair from Programs and Features (progress bar started then vanished)
6. Followed a tip on [windowsphoneinfo.com](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/pc-health-check-tool-do-not-open.566641/) to try `net user administrator /active:yes` but that was not allowed – and I checked: my user is an administrator
7. Tried a tip on [howto-connect.com](https://www.howto-connect.com/fix-pc-health-check-app-not-working-in-windows-10/) by running a `SFC /SCANNOW`

And the app still won't start, though its process shows in Task Manager > Details as PCHealthCheck.exe

8. Tried to kill all duplicate instances, and still nothing.

It's currently installed under: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\PCHealthCheck` if it helps; its current version: 3.3.2110.22002.

Comment: Try WhyNotWin11 from GitHub. It works somewhat better than Microsoft's tools. The fact that SFC did not solve the issue means something is wrong with your Windows 10 system.

Answer (score 0):

A comment suggested running DISM, but that too didn't work.

I think I figured it out. Unless one is enrolled in the Insider program, PC Health Check has been pulled since at least Aug 2021, and as of writing this, there are no new updates:

> After a feedback period with Windows Insiders and with the additional updates for the newly added processors, we plan to **re-release** the PC Health Check app for general availability in the coming weeks.

From [blogs.windows.com](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/08/27/update-on-windows-11-minimum-system-requirements-and-the-pc-health-check-app/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).